# When does Hibernate print statistics?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've recently integrated hibernate into my webapp and am trying to see the performance impact/frequency of db calls that are happening.

After enabling `show_sql` and `generate_statistics`, when I run the application I see the sql queries run by hibernate and also hibernate statistics. Eg:

```
08:04:53.724 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
85648 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

However the statistics statement gets printed multiple times per api call while the query statements are much lower in number. Also, its very rare to see a non zero value for any other metric except `acquiring 1 JDBC connections` in Statistics logs.

So when exactly does the logger run and what am I doing wrong to get so many metric logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you enable hibernate statistics you get session statistics information every time a session is closed.
if you dont want this behavior you can disable it with adding of following entry in your log4j file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener=OFF
```

Comment: So shouldn't every every statistic log also have a set of corresponding query/statements that were run in that session (which would be printed to console)? Why are statistics logs printed with only `getting JDBC connection` in most cases?

Comment: In fact in order to print statistics you must retrieve a statistics object from sessionFactory.
    Statistics stats =         sessionFactory.getStatistics();
then you can query statistics for different objects : Session, Entity, Collection, Cache. 
Refer to [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html) for more details.

Comment: in addition to default session metrics you can log every metrics you want, it's up to you, if you want metric on a particular entity you can call for exemple:
 Statistics stats = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
 EntityStatistics es = stats.getEntityStatistics(entityName);  System.out.println("Delete: " + es.getDeleteCount());

Comment: So i haven't done any of these above steps till now. Just enabled the logging and set the appropriate log level.If the number of session metrics printed is much more than the sql queries run, is this an indication that my annotations might not be correct? (Hibernate opening transactions for various function calls where they might not be needed etc)

Comment: Yes you're rigth,indeed it must be an indication that something goes wrong. With [session per request](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request) pattern which is the most common transactionnal pattern you should have a session metrics log per request.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to get to as deep as session events, you can disable them from getting logged by using this property "**hibernate.session.events.log=false**". (You may do it with your log4j configuration also, based on your needs).

It appears that since hibernate 4, if you enable "**hibernate.generate_statistics**", the session events are also logged by default. But the logs will get filled up heavily as the events are logged per session. So, use when you need to analyze any performance issues locally.

More details on enabling/disabling the event logs here:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8793

Answer (score 6):

It helped me:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      generate_statistics: false
```

in application.yml

Answer (score 1):

for **Quarkus** the relevant application.properties entry is:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.metrics.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I disabled it by using removing or disabling below property -

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics = false`

Answer (score 0):

We can disable logging specifically for this class by adding a property in logback.xml or log4j.xml file:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener" level="OFF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
spring:
  jpa:
      properties:
        hibernate:
          generate_statistics: false
```